# Regex with Sed "clean" a XML line

Tags: regex, xml, sed

I need to remove all the chracters from a line and only take the hour inside. The lines are like this:

```
<msg timestamp="20161004 16:24:56.638" level="INFO">Set BAT with value 1</msg>
```

and I need this result:

```
16:24:56.638
```

I tried this:

```
cat output.xml | grep -E "Set BAT with value 1" | sed 's/^<msg timestamp
=\"[0-9]+\s([0-9]+):?\.?\".+/{1}/g'
```

But for now seems impossible for me to get the proper result. Anyone?

Thanks!!

Comment: Better not to use `grep` or `sed` for parsing XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with `grep` and `pcre`, assuming `<msg>` tags line up well in same line

```
$ grep -oP '(\d+:){2}[\d.]+(?=.*Set BAT with value 1)' output.xml 
16:24:56.638
```

- `(\d+:){2}[\d.]+` pattern to extract
- `(?=.*Set BAT with value 1)` positive lookahead to see if line contains `Set BAT with value 1`

with `sed`

```
$ sed -nE '/Set BAT with value 1/ s/.* (([0-9]+:){2}[0-9.]+).*/\1/p' output.xml 
16:24:56.638
```

this solution has advantage over `grep` in that it allows to make inplace editing.